# Can I build a 3D model from scratch programmatically in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, 3d

I’m new to Swift, SwiftUI, and Apple platform development generally, but have been writing software for more than thirty years. I’m attempting to write my first app. Targeting iOS for now, but I’m interested in building the same thing for Mac and other platforms as well.

The idea is that the user will provide some numbers that specify the details of a shape (I would prefer not to specify, so as to not give away my idea), and then I use those numbers to compute the total geometry.

I’ve previously done this on the web, drawing the shape programmatically in 2D on a canvas element from two angles.

For the iOS version, I thought it would be fun to try doing it in 3D — building up a model based on the computed geometry and allowing the user to manipulate it on screen. (I’m well aware that I am jumping into some pretty deep water here for my first app!)

So far, I have the input and calculation portion of the app functioning, and I did just a tiny bit of rendering in 2D (just using shapes) before the 3D idea popped into my head.

I’ll need to do things like specify a somewhat complex 2D shape and then revolve it around an axis to define a more complex shape — for example, if you take a half circle and revolve it around its center, you’d get a sphere. What I need to do is similar, but the shape I’d be revolving is a compound set of curves and lines.

If possible, I’ll also want to be able to detect collisions between different parts of the model, such that I can alert the user that their input yields an impossible result.

I might also want the ability to export the generated model as a file for use elsewhere, like maybe Google Sketchup.

I’ve done a bunch of googling, and mostly I’ve found references to RealityKit and SceneKit (neither of which seems to be SwiftUI-enabled — I’d have to wrap a UIKit view in a Swift view).

I’ve also found a few things where people are layering and mutating 2D shapes to make it look like they’re spinning in 3D. That kind of trickery will not suffice here.

How should I approach this? If it’s possible, I would like to stick to pure SwiftUI.

If SwiftUI does not have provisions, I’ll take the next best thing, which in my mind would be the UIKit wrapper approach. I’m hoping to stay 100% Swift, as now seems like a weird time to learn Objective C. In this case, which *Kit or other framework is best suited to my needs?

Comment: You should use SceneKit to create 3D models, which is represented as a [`SCNGeometry`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scngeometry). There isn't anything built-in to "rotate" a shape in 3 dimensions, so you would need to calculate all the vertices yourself.

Comment: SwiftUI and UIKit are User Interaction frameworks. They have nothing to do with building 3D models. They can display them, observe interaction but everything else relies on another framework such as SceneKit or any third party out there.